# como debería recibir un valor desde ajax en mi ActionResult?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

este es mi script

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PlanVenta").change(function () {
            $("#Precio").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'@Url.Action("PreciosPorTipoVenta")',
                datatype:'json',
                data: { Id_Plan: $("#PlanVenta").val(), Id_Articulo: $("#Id_Articulo").val() },
                success: function (precios) {
                        $("#Precio").val(precios[0].precio);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

y  esto es lo que contiene

[image: y esto es lo que contiene]

Este es mi Controlador donde recibo un entero

```html
public JsonResult PreciosPorTipoVenta(Venta_Detalle vd, int Id_Plan,int Id_Articulo)
{
}
```

Aqui el html

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
        <th>
            <label>Articulo</label>
        </th>
        <th>
            <label>Nombre</label>
        </th>

        <th>
            <label>Precio</label>
        </th>


    </tr>
        @foreach (var v in Model)
                {
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                   <input type="hidden" name="Id_Articulo" id="Id_Articulo" value="@v.Articulo.Id" />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => v.Articulo.Nombre)
                   </td>
                   <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => v.Precio)
                   </td>
                  
                 </tr>
                }
  </table>
```

pero solo recibo un dato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como debo recibir los datos para que vengan completos o para recibir los tres elementos que se muestran en el ajax o que hago mal al enviarlo?

Nota:ya intente con `int[] Id_Articulo` ,`List<int>Id_Articulo` pero sale lo mismo

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo del php controlador?

Comment: y si colocas el HTML completo?

Comment: Y lo demás? Recuerda que quienes deseamos colaborar con la respuesta debemos tener el código de tal manera que podamos reproducir lo mismo que estás viendo

Comment: Me refería a todo el código de la vista...

Comment: @fredyfx es que es una lista ya lo edite de nuevo no se si asi este bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes varios input con el mismo id debes definir otro tipo de selector, lo comun es usar el `class`

```
<input type="hidden" class="articulo" name="Id_Articulo" id="Id_Articulo" value="@v.Articulo.Id" />
```

entonces usarias

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PlanVenta").change(function () {
            $("#Precio").empty();

            var params = { 
                            Id_Plan: $("#PlanVenta").val(), 
                            Id_Articulo: []
                        };

            $(".articulo").each(function(index, item){
                params.Id_Articulo.push($(item).val());
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'@Url.Action("PreciosPorTipoVenta")',
                datatype:'json',
                data: params,
                success: function (precios) {
                        $("#Precio").val(precios[0].precio);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

como veras iteras por los articulos realizando un `push()` en el array, entonces si define un `List<int>` como parametro del action

Comment: funciona ya la marque gracias!!!